# RN Weird style behaviour when mapping over array of elements

Tags: react-native

Anyone knows why my text goes out of screen? I want to have 7 entries on a row and then the next 7 on the next row. The array will have 28 entries at all times no matter what. My expected behaviour was text spans across the screen for the Width I have to the container then goes to the next line

```
<View
    style={{
     flexDirection: 'row',
     marginTop: 20,
     width: screenWidth - 60,
    }}
>
 {lastMonthDays.map((day, index) => (
   <Text key={`Day-${index}`}>
     {day}
   </Text>
  ))}
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve your requirement by adding `flexWrap: "wrap"` to your parent style. Since you want to have 7 entries on a row make sure to assign width of `Text` as below,

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 20,
    width: screenWidth,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  }}
>
  {lastMonthDays.map((day, index) => (
    <Text
      style={{
        width: screenWidth / 7,
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
      key={`Day-${index}`}
    >
      {day}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.